# need to flag every 60 days from a date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find the easiest way to create a field that flags every 60 days from a date field in sql.  I have dates that go back to 2001 so I only want to show the most recent 60 day period.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results  What does "create a field that flags every 60 days" really mean?

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-60,GETDATE())

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourTable.DateField >= DATEADD(DAY,-60, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```